# Finish CSS animation before page change with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple page load progress bar with CSS and a bit of JS. I already made a working css, but the problem is the bar shows up after page change, when I would like it to firstly finish the css progress bar animation and then load next page.

HTML animation code:

```
<div class="progress-css"></div>
```

CSS animation code:

```
:root {
  --progress-duration: 0.8s;
  --progress-height: 2.5px;
  --progress-color: rgb(35,163,255);
  --progress-color-ending: rgba(35,163,255,0.2);
  --progress-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(0,148,255,0.23);
}

.progress-css {
  position: fixed;
  height: var(--progress-height);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  animation: progress-load var(--progress-duration);
  -webkit-animation: progress-load var(--progress-duration);
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes progress-load {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    box-shadow: var(--progress-shadow);
    width: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 20%;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 28%;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 85%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--progress-color-ending);
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

Now, when I will click on a `<a href="subpage.html">Redirect</a>` tag on a website, it will load the specified page, and then it will display progress animation. I would like it to firstly display progress animation, and then load the next page.

I would be grateful for an answer to my question.

Comment: So basically you have a loader?

Comment: @DumbCoder7 Yes, it's a loader displayed as a progress bar at the top of the page. If you don't know what I mean, go to YouTube and switch between pages, you will see a red loading bar at the top of the page every time you switch the page.

Comment: If you have the transition duration fixed, why not request the page load after that duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has an [`animationend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) that can be used to detect when a keyframe animation is complete. Ideally you would wait to add this listener after any required data (if applicable) is completed loading so it doesn't just arbitrarily advance if loading is still in-progress.

```
document.querySelector('.progress-css').addEventListener('animationend', e=>{
    //go to next page or similar
    window.location.href = 'subpage.html';
});
```

**Updated example based on more details from the comments:**

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-css');

//add a listener to all of the links; modify the query if it should be restricted to specific links
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the default behavior of navigating to a link when clicking an <a> tag
    setupLoadingBar( link.href );
  });
});

const setupLoadingBar = url => {
  const cleanupLoadingBarAndNavigate = e => {
    progressBar.removeEventListener('animationend', cleanupLoadingBarAndNavigate); //removing this each time is important to ensure that it doesn't run multiple times if you don't actually navigate away

    progressBar.classList.remove('loading');
   
    alert('Navigate to: '+url);

    //uncomment this to actually navigate to the url
    //window.location.href = url;
  }
  
  progressBar.classList.add('loading');
  progressBar.addEventListener('animationend', cleanupLoadingBarAndNavigate);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --progress-duration: 4s;
  --progress-height: 2.5px;
  --progress-color: rgb(35,163,255);
  --progress-color-ending: rgba(35,163,255,0.2);
  --progress-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(0,148,255,0.23);
}

.progress-css {
  position: fixed;
  height: var(--progress-height);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  display:none;
}

.loading {
  display:block;
  animation: progress-load var(--progress-duration);
  -webkit-animation: progress-load var(--progress-duration);
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes progress-load {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    box-shadow: var(--progress-shadow);
    width: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 20%;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 28%;
  }
  90% {
    background-color: var(--progress-color);
    width: 85%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--progress-color-ending);
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

<div class="progress-css"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I have multiple links on my website? Also, when I ran this code, it made an infinite redirect loop to subpage.html alternating with progress bar animation.

Comment: @talaing, can you explain more of what you mean by "load" in this case? Are you trying to do some type of preloading where the link is loaded via JavaScript/AJAX in the background, or just wanting to display the animation before changing pages to give the illusion of something loading? (It's a valid UX technique; no shame in faking it.) If it's the former (preloading), that's far beyond the scope of a SO question. I can help more with the latter though.

Comment: No need to preload specified page in the background - I just want to make illusion of something loading.

Comment: @talaing updated the answer with a new code sample that shows how to do it with multiple links